# gcc linking of shared libraries: secondary dependencies with $ORIGIN

Tags: gcc, dependency-injection, shared-libraries, ld, rpath

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058041/correct-usage-of-rpath-relative-vs-absolute).

I understand that using `$ORIGIN` in the `-rpath` option generates a dynamic absolute path that will always point to the specified location - no matter from where I use the library.

What's confusing me, is the following: I use this library to generate a shared binary and I set (again) the `-Wl,-rpath` option using `$ORIGIN` to enable the binary to always find its library. Now the original `$ORIGIN` value of the library is not available anymore or wrong because it seems to be overwritten by the new one.

Somehow this is understandable since I am now generating a new shared object - the binary - that has its own `$ORIGIN`. A way around this, would be to provide the binary's `-rpath` with both locations, the one to the library and the one the library itself needs. In my opinion this makes `-rpath` almost useless, because I can't just link to the library and specify its location I also need to specify the library's dependency location.

My question: Is there a way to specify hierarchical `-rpath` values using `$ORIGIN`? I would like to avoid absolute paths, which would obviously fix my issue.

Comment: Here's nice explanation of the problem: http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/

Comment: It is possible to set an `rpath` inside the library, e.g. if you have App A depending on lib B which depends on lib C, you can `patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/.' libB.so` to make it look for `libC.so` in the same directory as `libB.so`, regardless of where that is or if it is linked into A explicitly.  Does that help?