# Dynamic library cannot load when running program outside build directory

Tags: makefile, compilation, linker, g++, dynamic-linking

I have the following Makefile:

```
OBJ=main.o other.o other1.o other2.o
LINKDIVSUF=-L libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/ -ldivsufsort64 -Wl,-R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/  
INCDIVSUF=-I libdivsufsort-master/build/include -ldivsufsort64                                       
EXE=program                                                                                             
COMPFLAGS=-MMD -fopenmp -std=c++17 -O3                                                   
CXX=g++                                                                                              

$(EXE):$(OBJ)                                                                                        
  $(CXX) $(COMPFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE) $(LINKDIVSUF) -lz -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options       

%.o: %.cpp                                                                                           
  $(CXX) $(COMPFLAGS) $(INCDIVSUF) -c $<                                                             
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

The `program` links to a dynamic library, `libdivsufsort64.so.3`, located from the build directory at `./libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/`. 
Use of `-Wl,-R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/`is to avoid having to concatenate `absolute/path/to/libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order to run `program`. Indeed, when I `make` `program`
without `-Wl, -R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/`, and without setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as mentioned and subsequently run `program`, I get the following error message:

```
./program: error while loading shared libraries: libdivsufsort64.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

With `-Wl, -R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/`, `program` runs successfully with no alteration to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but only when
I run  `program` **from the same directory in which it was built**. 
If I try to run `program` when compiled with `-Wl, -R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/` **from any other directory, it fails to run,** terminating with
the aforementioned error message.

How can I change the `g++` compilation options (or anything else at compilation time) to enable `program` to run from
any directory whilst avoiding the need to alter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? The only "solution" I have found is to concatenate `libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. By doing so, I can run `program` from any
directory, thus removing the need to compile with `Wl,-R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/`, however, this of course requires the user of `program` to manually set their `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which I specifically want to avoid.

**Solution**
Reading this post [that discusses the use of relative or absolute paths with -R (-rpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058041/correct-usage-of-rpath-relative-vs-absolute) I came up with this solution.

Append the following lines, such that the Makefile is now:

```
libdivsufsort_lib = $(addprefix $(shell pwd), /libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/)        
libdivsufsort_include = $(addprefix $(shell pwd), /libdivsufsort-master/build/include/)
OBJ=main.o other.o other1.o other2.o
LINKDIVSUF=-L libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/ -ldivsufsort64 -Wl,-R libdivsufsort-master/build/lib/  
INCDIVSUF=-I libdivsufsort-master/build/include -ldivsufsort64                                       
EXE=program                                                                                             
COMPFLAGS=-MMD -fopenmp -std=c++17 -O3                                                   
CXX=g++                                                                                              

$(EXE):$(OBJ)                                                                                        
  $(CXX) $(COMPFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE) $(LINKDIVSUF) -lz -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options       

%.o: %.cpp                                                                                           
  $(CXX) $(COMPFLAGS) $(INCDIVSUF) -c $<                                                             
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

This avoids the use of `$ORIGIN`, to produce an absolute path to `program`s
directory, which is not supported on some systems. The two additional
lines produce the absolute path irrespective of the binary's location - 
it just needs to kept in the build directory and compiled again if the build
directory moves. Importantly, `program` can now be called from outside the 
build directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$ORIGIN` with `-Wl,-R` to locate the library in relative path:

```
LINKDIVSUF = ... -Wl,-R,'$ORIGIN/libdivsufsort-master/build/lib'
```