# linux how to specify dynamic library when there're multiple

Tags: c++, linux, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I'm developing a shared library, and on my machine there could be two copies of the same shared library:

1. the one I installed to the system path: `/usr/lib/libmyproject.so`
2. the one I built in my workspace during my development: `/home/ziqi.liu/workspace/myproject/build/src/libmyproject.so`

So during my development, there're some executables under `/home/ziqi.liu/workspace/myproject/build`. I want them to use the dynamic library in `/home/ziqi.liu/workspace/myproject/build/src/libmyproject.so`, however it turns out that they're actually using `/usr/lib/libmyproject.so` when I use `ldd` to check the link library.

Is there anyway to specify which dynamic library to use when there are multiple?  It would be better if I can specify this for all executables under "this project", since it's very intuitive to link the dynamic library in the same repo I just built, instead of the one installed to the system path.

**UPDATED:**
I've found this post: [Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/)

It seems that the dynamic library searching has something to do with
the `rpath` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.

What I want is to search for `rpath` first, and then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

According to [rpath wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath), the `rpath` is named `DT_RPATH`, however when I `objdump` that executable, the only thing I can find is `RUNPATH` section. I'm not sure if this is a compiler-specific behavior... (I'm running `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`)

Comment: Please shows how you compile currently (makefile/cmake) in [mre]. So you'll get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to specify which dynamic library to use when there are multiple?

The best way to achieve this is to use the special `$ORIGIN` tag in the executable.

Assuming you have `$D/build/exe` and you want that `exe` to use `$D/build/src/libmyproject.so`, link your `exe` with: `-rpath '$ORIGIN/src'`.

This would allow you to have several `build` directories (e.g. "release" and "debug" builds), and each binary will pick up the library from its own build tree.

It would also allow you to not install `libmyproject.so` into `/usr/lib` at all -- you can keep the binary and the all the required libraries in e.g. `/usr/local/$project/{bin/exe,lib/libmyproject.so}` and have it all just work(TM).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058216/50617).

Answer (score -1):

Just modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and put your home folder first, like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ziqi.liu/workspace/myproject/build/src/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Then it should be fine.