# gcc error –Wl,-rpath,./ffmpeg/lib: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg

I got a gcc error. It is a strange error.

When I compile the 'muxing.c' without "–Wl,-rpath=./ffmpeg/lib", the code is successfully compiled.

```
gcc -o muxing muxing.c -I ./ffmpeg/include -L ./ffmpeg/lib -lavcodec -lavfilter -lavutil -lswresample -lavdevice -lavformat -lpostproc -lswscale -lm -lpthread -lasound
nvidia@nx:~/Desktop/project$ ls
ffmpeg  Makefile  muxing  muxing.c  test.cpp
```

But once I add "–Wl,-rpath=./ffmpeg/lib", the compiler give this error: –Wl,-rpath=./ffmpeg/lib: No such file or directory

```
gcc -o muxing muxing.c -I ./ffmpeg/include -L ./ffmpeg/lib -lavcodec -lavfilter -lavutil -lswresample -lavdevice -lavformat -lpostproc -lswscale -lm -lpthread -lasound –Wl,-rpath,'./ffmpeg/lib'
gcc: error: –Wl,-rpath=./ffmpeg/lib: No such file or directory
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'muxing' failed
make: *** [muxing] Error 1
```

The gcc option -I and -L can find the path, but '–Wl,-rpath=' cannot find this path. Why?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a relative path this way. Check out the `$ORIGIN` option. For instance, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058270/7868781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your option, probably because you copied it from a formatted text.

The leading "-" is not the correct character. So GCC interprets it as a filename character and tries to open a file with the name of the complete option "–Wl,-rpath,'./ffmpeg/lib'", as the error message tells.