# Bundling FFMPEG using CMAKE and RPATH

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake, rpath, runpath

As the title explains, I am trying to bundle FFMPEG with my executable application.

However, I can't seem to figure out the runtime loading of the FFMPEG shared libraries. I'm not sure what is incorrect:

- `RPATH/RUNPATH` of main project and FFMPEG libraries.
- The CMake install steps.
- Or just my entire approach (most likely).

This is a CMake project and in hope of finally finding a "standard solution", I am going to include everything needed to reproduce this issue.

#### *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21) # Required for the install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET...) subcommand
project(cmake-demo LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS NO)

set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN YES)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Setup CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for `find_package`
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/install)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(ffmpeg REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice libavfilter libavformat libavcodec
    libswresample libswscale libavutil)

# Setup variable representing the vendor install directory
set(VENDOR_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/install)
# Set RPATH to the dependency install tree
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN/../deps)

# Add our executable target
add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_include_directories(demo PRIVATE ${VENDOR_PATH}/include)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE PkgConfig::ffmpeg)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS demo RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET runtime_deps)
install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET runtime_deps
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/deps
    # DIRECTORIES ${VENDOR_PATH}/lib
    POST_EXCLUDE_REGEXES "^/lib" "^/usr" "^/bin")
```

#### *main.cpp*:

```cpp
extern "C"{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "FFMPEG AVCODEC VERSION: " << avcodec_version() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Instructions:

###### Setup FFMPEG (this can take awhile...):

```
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodules vendor/src/ffmpeg
git checkout release/5.0
export INSTALL_PATH=$PWD/vendor/install
cd vendor/src/ffmpeg
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
# WITH RPATH (HARDCODED TO VENDOR install directory)
# ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldflags=-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_PATH/lib --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
make -j16 V=1
make install
cd ../../..
```

###### CMake Commands:

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install
cmake --build build -j16 #-v
cmake --install build
```

###### Cleanup between steps:

```sh
# Run from top-level dir of project
rm -rf build install
rm -rf vendor/install # ONLY if you need to modify the FFMPEG step.
```

## Investigation:

1. Following the direction of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058041/correct-usage-of-rpath-relative-vs-absolute/38058216#38058216) post I set the `RPATH/RUNPATH` of the executable to `$ORIGIN/../deps` and no RPATH on the FFMPEG libraries.

- When I do this, the cmake install step fails complaining that `libavutil.so` cannot be resolved in the `install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET...)` function. This does make sense because the generated `cmake_install.cmake` script in the `build` directory is moving the demo executable to the install directory and performing `file(RPATH_CHANGE...)` on the executable prior to doing the runtime dependency set analysis. According to the CMake documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies) and using `readelf -d demo` the `RUNPATH` of the executable is `$ORIGIN/../deps` and only case #1 from the docs apply here so the library isn't found at all.

2. From the CMake documentation referenced in [1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies), there is a `DIRECTORIES` argument for the `install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET...)` function that can be used as a search path. When combining the setup in 1, uncommenting this in `CMakeLists.txt` and rerunning all the CMake commands, the installation is successful (although as documented, CMake does emit warnings for all the dependencies found using `DIRECTORIES`). However, running the executable (i.e. `./install/bin/demo`) is unsuccessful because the runtime loader cannot locate `libswresample.so`. Debugging into this a little further, I ran `export LD_DEBUG=libs` and tried to relaunch the executable. This shows that the runtime loader is finding `libavcodec.so` using the `$ORIGIN/../deps` RUNPATH from `demo`. However, when searching for the transitive dependency (i.e. `libavcodec.so`'s dep. on `libswresample.so`), the `RUNPATH` of `demo` is NOT searched, instead the loader falls back to the system path and the library is not found.
3. I was able to satisfy CMake and the loader by setting the RPATH on the FFMPEG libraries and not using the `DIRECTORIES` argument with the CMake `install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET...)` sub-command. CMake runs without any warnings and the executable loads/runs as expected. However, this is NOT a viable solution because when inspecting the libraries in the `install/deps` folder with `ldd`, the `libswresample.so` and other libraries are pointing back to the `vendor/install` directory which is not going to be present in the bundle when deployed.

Does anyone know what the standard approach is or what I am missing above? I am open to any and all suggestions/tools but I am doing this in an attempt to learn what is "standard practice" and am hoping to extend this to a cross-platform solution (i.e Windows/macOS). As a result, I would like to avoid messing with the system level loader configuration (`ldconfig`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Reproducing the Issue

To try to reproduce your problem, I actually discarded all CMake stuff and just compiled `main.cpp` from the command line. I think you'll agree that the root of the issue is in the `ffmpeg` build.

```
g++ -I vendor/install/include -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -L vendor/install/lib -o main main.o -lavcodec
```

The output looked like this:

```
usr/bin/ld: warning: libswresample.so.4, needed by vendor/install/lib/libavcodec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.57, needed by vendor/install/lib/libavcodec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: vendor/install/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `av_opt_set_int@LIBAVUTIL_57'
/usr/bin/ld: vendor/install/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `av_get_picture_type_char@LIBAVUTIL_57'
# many more lines of undefined references
```

You can make this go away by adding `-rpath-link`...

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,vendor/install/lib -L vendor/install/lib -o main main.o -lavcodec
```

but the executable fails with this error:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If you use `-rpath` instead of `-rpath-link`, you get this error instead:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libswresample.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This last error is because `libavcodec.so` references `libwresample.so`, and doesn't have it in its RPATH. `main` finds `libavcodec.so` successfully, but then the dynamic linker gets stuck.

#### Solving the Issue

From what I can tell, the ffmpeg `configure` script sanitizes the arguments passed in via `--extra-ldflags` and it's variants. No matter how hard you try, I don't think it will allow you to pass in a `$` sign in this way. To pass in un-sanitized arguments, you should set `LDFLAGS` (and its variants) in the environment when you call `configure`. The end goal is to get the string `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` into the command to create each library, which means we want that value assigned to `LDSOFLAGS`. Let's start by passing it in straight:

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' ../configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
```

Looking in `src/build/ffbuild/config.mak` we see the following line:

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN
```

In this case, the single quotes were interpreted by the shell running the `configure` command, so they don't appear in the generated makefile.

If we escape the single quotes, however, then the shell will expand the `$ORIGIN` environment variable (empty, in this case), and produce this line:

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,''
```

If you put "real" single quotes inside the escaped ones, however...

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\''$ORIGIN'\' ../configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
```

it produces the correct line:

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
```

Now, however, there is the problem that `make` *also* uses `$` signs. Typically we could escape the `$` sign by replacing it with `$$`. *However*, you can see in `src/ffbuild/library.mak` that `LDSOFLAGS` is used inside of `define RULES`, which is then applied with the line `$(eval $(RULES))`. This will expand `LDSOFLAGS` and any variables inside of it immediately, which means the `$$` will be replaced with a single `$` in the final version of the recipe, *so*, we need to use *four* `$` signs to survive the expansion in the `eval` as well as the expansion when the recipe is executed.

```
LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\''$$$$ORIGIN'\' ../configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
```

For completeness, let's also define `LDEXEFLAGS`, so that the `ffmpeg` executable works properly. Notice that `LDEXEFLAGS` only requires two `$` signs (you would have to look in the makefiles to know this).

```
LDEXEFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\''$$ORIGIN/../lib'\' LDSOFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\''$$$$ORIGIN'\' ../configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pic --enable-lto --extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldexeflags=-pie
```

After building and installing, the last thing to do is to make sure `main` also has the correct `RPATH`:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/vendor/install/lib' -L vendor/install/lib -o main main.o -lavcodec
```

And here's the result:

```
$ ./main
FFMPEG AVCODEC VERSION: 3871332
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a detailed analysis and explanation. I finally got around to testing this from my bash shell and can confirm that it works as described. In my actual project I am using a Python script to drive the build and in that context I didn't need to escape the single quotes on each end of the rpath. Thank you again!